# Kentico 10 Password Expiration via C#

Tags: c#, kentico

With Kentico 10, how can users have their passwords expired programmatically using c#?  UserInfo.UserPasswordExpiration doesn't have a setter (so only read-only).  I am importing a bunch of users (which is working) and I would like to force the users to reset their password on first login.

Answer (score 2):

To properly check and set this you need to

Check if Password expiration is enabled:

```
int num;    
bool isEnabled = AuthenticationHelper.IsPasswordExpirationEnabled("Sitename", out num);
```

Then check when the user last changed their password:

```
TimeSpan dateTime = UserInfoProvider.DateTimeNow = MembshipContext.AuthenticatedUser.UserPasswordLastChanged;
int daysSinceLastChange = num - dateTime.Days;
```

So if `daysSinceLastChange` is a positive value, the password is expired by that number of days.  If `daysSinceLastChange` is a negative value, the password will expire in those days.

To properly set this you need to do a few things:

- Make sure Enable password expiration is enabled.  Settings>Security & Membership>Passwords>Password Expiration.
- Make sure you have a valid password expiration period in days in Settings>Security & Membership>Passwords>Password Expiration
- Set the `UserPasswordLastChanged` value to something ridiculous like 10 years ago on the user you want to invalidate.  You can do this when importing the users or via the API.